# Populate a database gives strange results

Tags: database, delphi

I have a database and I need to populate it's first 2 columns on every row. The first column is the date and the second column is an id.

My code is as follows:

```
.......    
febr29:array[1..12] of byte = (31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
.......

procedure TForm.populate_database;
var
  i,j,m,n: Integer;
begin

  for i := 1 to 12 do
    for j := 1 to febr29[i] do
       for m := 1 to 9 do
          for n := 1 to 15 do begin

             database.tbl1.Append;
             database.tbl1['date']:= inttostr(j)+'.'+inttostr(i)+'.2016';
             database.tbl1['id']:='a'+inttostr(m)+inttostr(n);
             database.tbl1.Post;

          end;

end;
```

So basically I need to have all the ids on all the days of the year. But I have a problem with the code above: it gives me some strange output in the database, as in the following picture:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for me it looks like a sorting problem in your database. Make a query for one day and sort after id, like: SELECT * FROM Table WHERE date = '23.9.2016' ORDER BY id
Then you can check if there are all wanted ids

Comment: What looks strange depends on what you are expecting to see.  What *exactly* do you think is "strange" about the display?  To me, the thing which looks strange is the way you are constructing the value for your ID field.

Comment: @ChristineRoss : yes, it is a sorting problem in the database. but what it's causing the problem?, since the database gets 'sorted' in the loops that i posted. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MartynA: the strange thing for me is that the database is not sorted the way I was planning with the loops I posted. What could the problem be?

Comment: Excuse this question, but you do realise that numbers represented as strings do not sort in the same order as the same numbers represented as integers?  With string representations you get '1,' '11', '12', '2', '20' etc, not 1, 2, ...11, 12.

Comment: @MartynA: I think I don't understand how databases work. The mechanism I have in mind is this: i append all the records of the database one by one in the loops I posted. So whenever I append a record(append means it gets written at the end of the table, or am I wrong?), I edit the values of columns 'date' and 'id' using the integers(converted to strings) with which i'm looping increasevely in the for instructions. So normally if i would write that in a text file(with writeln instruction instead of append), I think I would get the expected results. Why is this happening with the database?

Comment: Which database are you using?  Anyway, whether or not it's a SQL-based one, you should bare in mind that a database doesn't necessarily return records in any particular order unless you tell it to, because databases typically re-use the space left by deleted records.  With a SQL-based server, you can specify an order using an Order By Clause in your query.  For non-SQL-based databases, typically you specify an order by using an index defined on the table.  Either way, there is the difference between numeric ordering and string ordering I mentioned in my earlier comment.

Comment: Why are you a) inventing your own date format instead of using the database data type? It makes your loop much easier, eliminates the need for the array (which is wrong in a non-leap year when there are only 28 days in Feb); and b) inventing your own, difficult to work with and sort ID instead of just using the DBs autoincrement or identity type?

Answer (score 0):

If your ID field is supposed to identify the data row, it would be better to declare it in the database as an integer column, not a character/string one.

It would also be better & less error prone not to try and calculate it from your loop variables, but use a running counter instead

```
procedure TForm.populate_database;
var
  i,j,m,n: Integer;
  ID : Integer;
begin
  ID := 0;
  for i := 1 to 12 do
    for j := 1 to febr29[i] do
       for m := 1 to 9 do
          for n := 1 to 15 do begin
             Inc(ID);
             database.tbl1.Append;
             database.tbl1['date']:= inttostr(j)+'.'+inttostr(i)+'.2016';
             database.tbl1['id'].AsInteger :=ID;
             database.tbl1.Post;
```

Of course, if you must have the 'a' prefix and a character coumn type for some reason, you could do

```
             database.tbl1['id'].AsString :='a' + IntToStr(ID);
```

but even that may give you results you aren't expecting, unless to pad the result of IntToStr(ID) to a fixed length with leading zeroes.

Comment: Martin, I tried your example (even it's not what I need), and the database still is not sorted [link]http://i.imgur.com/ca7WNQ5.jpg[/link]. The id column is not an index of all the rows. I also don't do string sorting or number sorting, I just append to the database in the order which I need after that. I don't delete or alter records at this point. The database I'm using is a microsoft access database. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: ´@new delphi user: From my point of view you have two/three options:
1 Open table in access and set an index on these columns. How to do this depends very much on the version of access
2. Don't bother of the sort in the table, but use for further use a query where you can sort after specific fields
3. Get some book about database design: have you ever heard something about primary key, secondary indexes, query/view etc.?

Comment: @newdelphiuser:  In your screenshot, if the 2nd column is the ID one, you are obviously **not** doing what I suggested in my answer because the iD values are duplicated in many rows.  The other thing is you simply **cannot** rely on a db engine to return rows in the order you inserted them **unless you explicitly specify, when you retrieve them, the order they should be returned in.